# question regarding GUI in java

Tags: java

HOW TO pass the string input in GUI using JTextfield to other class in java.

Comment: Rule of thumb: please put as much effort into formulating and asking your question as you would hope someone would put in in answering it.

Answer (score 2):

```
otherclass.setText (jTextField.getText ());
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the amount of details provided in the question, here is an approximate answer

```
String text = jTextField.getText();
OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(text);
```