# question regarding GUI in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [question regarding GUI in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918935/question-regarding-gui-in-java)

how to input string in JTextfield in java

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: -1 You asked **exactly** [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918935/question-regarding-gui-in-java), with exactly the same lack of context and details an hour ago - *and* you **even got some answers which you neither replied to nor accepted**. Smells like a troll.

Answer (score 1):

Read the java tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html